# I am stuck with this code,having doubts about the FILE structure and fopen function

Tags: c, pointers, arm, fopen, bitmapimage

```
 typedef struct tagFileheader    
{
  unsigned short   Type;                  //  00h  File Type Identifier to check if the file is bmp or not
  unsigned int     FileSize;              //  02h  Size of bmp file No.of bytes of the bitmap file           
  unsigned int     PxOffset;              //  0Ah  Offset to bitmap pixel data  
}Fileheader;

 Fileheader filehdr;
 Fileheader *pFileheader = &filehdr;

 unsigned short Get16U(unsigned int *x)
 {
     unsigned short temp;
     temp = *x & (0xFFFF);
     return temp;
 }  

 unsigned int Get32U(unsigned int *x)
 {
    unsigned int temp;
    temp = *x ;
    return temp; 
 }

 int Get32(unsigned int *x)
 {
    int temp;
    temp = *x ;
    return temp; 
 }

void main()
{
    unsigned int headersize,i ;  

    bAddress = fopen("D:/Tapan/Projects/Jacquard/BMP/03Body.bmp","rb");  // open the file and send the start address of its memory location                               

    pFileheader->Type = Get16U(bAddress);                 // save the first two bytes of bmp file data 
    (char*)bAddress++;
    (char*)bAddress++;                                    // increment the address by 2 bytes to reach address of "Filesize" parameter 

    if(pFileheader->Type == bmpSIGNATURE)                 // read further bytes of the FILE header and INFO header only if the file is a bitmap 
     { 

        pFileheader->FileSize   = Get32U(bAddress);         // save the filesize
        bAddress = bAddress + 2;                            // increment the address by 8 bytes to reach address of "offset" parameter

        pFileheader->PxOffset    = Get32U(bAddress);        // save the offset
        bAddress++;                                         // increment the address by 4 bytes to reach address of "info header size" parameter
     }
}
```

Here is my code.
My main intention in this code is to read the bmp file header.I want to declare a pointer which will hold the start address of the buffer which will be created by fopen().And using that start address i will read the data from buffer.
I am using this code in ARM controller.
This is not the full code.

Before main i have declared bAddress globally as -

```
unsigned int *bAddress
```

When i compile the code i get following error -- a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned int*'
Now mY question is that,is my pointer declaration correct?
I have seen FILE being used to declare a pointer variable for fopen()
How should i use FILE here.How should i declare the structure of FILE

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
(char*)bAddress++;
(char*)bAddress++;
```

will not move the `FILE*` by two characters. In fact, it will render `bAddress` unusable. What you need is:

```
fgetc(bAddress);
fgetc(bAddress);
```

However, I have a feeling changing those two lines won't solve your problems. You obviously don't understand how to use a `FILE*` to perform I/O. You need to spend some time reading up on how file I/O works using `FILE*` before using it in a real program.

You can start with a tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm.

Comment: not to mention that fopen(..) will not compile cause it will return a `FILE*` and not a char pointer

Comment: what is the structure of FILE

Comment: @tapanchawda, the structure of `FILE` depends on the implementation. The language does not specify it. It only specifies how to use `FILE*`.

Comment: So in my case how should i declare the FILE structure.

Comment: `FILE* inFile = fopen("..", "r");` Specify the file name instead of `".."`.

Comment: i just want the start address of the bmp file that i will open using fopen function

Comment: @tapanchawda, that comment is another indication that you need to get more knowledgeable about file I/O using C.

Comment: i have added more code which shows how i will get the value from the pointed address and how i will increment the pointer

Comment: @tapanchawda More code doesn't make it any less wrong - To reiterate: `fopen()` does not "create a buffer". A `FILE *` is just a pointer to a some file descriptor structure private to the C library - there is no "value to get from it", and incrementing it is nonsensical. There is no "start address of the file" - you have to allocate your own buffer and use `fread()` or similar to get the data into memory where you can access it. There are countless tutorials and documentation out there to help you learn how file I/O in C works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good idea to read bmp file in text mode. Use binary mode `"rb"` (not `"r"`) and `fread ()` function, and do not change pointer to file structure, as well as data in FILE's fields directly.